# How to plot a function from the sphere to the reals as a colored sphere?

Tags: plotting, color

Given a point $\{x,y,z\}$ on the sphere, the function

```
dist[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[x + y];
```

is some positive number. If the range of `dist` over the sphere happens to be e.g. $[2,5]$, then the sphere should be red when `dist[x, y, z] == 2` and green when `dist[x, y, z] == 5`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π/2, π/2},
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, dist[#, #2, #3]] &)]
```

doesn't work because I don't know the range of `dist` in advance.

I can't find a suitable plot function to write

```
OtherPlotFunction[dist[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[],
                  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, #] &)]
```

What plot function am I missing?

Comment: I think that something is wrong in the statement. You want to plot a colored unit sphere, however, $(x,y)$ coordinates can range to values within `2<=Abs[x+y]<=5`, how can this be posible? Maybe, I am missing something...

Comment: One problem is that it should be `dist[x_, y_, z_] := Abs[x + y]` instead of `dist[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[x + y]`. Then you can just do `SliceDensityPlot3D[dist[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, #] &)]`.

Comment: @Rahul Very nice thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you do not know the range *a priori* you can run the plot once to get it, then again to plot:

```
dist[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[x + y];
range = dist @@@ 
   Reap[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 
       0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
      ColorFunction :> (Sow[{#1, #2, #3}] &)]][[2, 1]] // MinMax
```

> {0.292893, 1.70711}

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
 ColorFunction :> (Blend[{{range[[1]], Red}, {range[[2]], Green}}, 
     dist[#1, #2, #3]] &)]
```

[image]

Note that the arguments passed to the color function are scaled coordinates ranging from zero to one over the graphics box.  Most likely you want to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` (both `ParametricPlot3D` uses), then you get the expected range,

> {3.56064*10^-14, 1.41421}  (* 0 to Sqrt[2] *)

and plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For unit sphere: $0\le |x+y|\le\sqrt{2}$:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Blend[{Red, Green}, Abs[x + y]/Sqrt[2]]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Green}, #] &, {0, Sqrt[2]}}], 
 MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#1 + #2] &}, Mesh -> 5, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When radius == 4, 0 < Abs[x + y] < 2 Sqrt@2.

`ParametricPlot[{u, 4 Abs[Cos[u] Cos[v] + Sin[u] Cos[v]]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}]`

[image]

```
dist[x_, y_, z_]   := Abs[x + y];
normalizeDist[v_]  := (v - 2)/3;
color[v_]          := Which[v >= 0 && v <= 1, Blend[{Red, Green}, v], True, White] 
normalizeColor[x_, y_, z_] := dist[x, y, z] // normalizeDist // color

ParametricPlot3D[
 4 {Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
 ColorFunction -> (normalizeColor[#1, #2, #3] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]